# Finding duplicate values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to code a system which will find user accounts that are using the same IPs, and print out the matches with their keys. I have already coded the part where the data is pulled from MySQL and nicely put in a multidimensional associative array, so input looks like this (the key is UserID, values are IP addresses):

```
$users = array(
               100 => array("1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"),
               200 => array("1.1.1.1","4.4.4.4","5.5.5.5"),
               300 => array("1.1.1.1","4.4.4.4","7.7.7.7")
              );
```

The expected output would be:

```
Array
(
    [1.1.1.1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 300
        )

    [4.4.4.4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 300
        )
)
```

I have searched and used trial and error with multiple nested foreach that would loop through the arrays, tried array_intersect to find the duplicates, but nothing gets me close to the expected output. By now I think I'm overthinking the problem and the solution is really easy, but I cannot seem to get close to the expected output. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend doing this using MySQL instead, with a combination of `COUNT` and `HAVING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = array();
// loop through each user
foreach ($users as $id => $ips) {
    // loop through each IP address
    foreach ($ips as $ip) {
        // add IP address, if not present
        if (!isset($output[$ip])) {
            $output[$ip] = array();         
        }
        // add user ID to the IP address' array
        $output[$ip][] = $id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = array(
                100 => array("1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"),
                200 => array("1.1.1.1","4.4.4.4","5.5.5.5"),
                300 => array("1.1.1.1","4.4.4.4","7.7.7.7")
                );

$allIP = [];
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $allIP = array_merge($allIP, $user);
}
$allIP = array_unique($allIP);

$result = [];
foreach ( $allIP as $ip ) {
    foreach ( $users as $key => $val ) {
        if ( in_array($ip, $val, true) ) {
            if ( !isset($result[$ip]) ) {
                $result[$ip] = [];
            }
            array_push($result[$ip], $key);
        }
    }
}

$result = array_filter($result, function ($v, $k) {
    if ( count($v) > 1 ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

var_dump($result);
```

Although I think it's better to do this by SQL as well. It could be extremely slow to achieve this by PHP.